# Remove internet access without losing LAN

Tags: linux, ssh, networking, cluster, lan

I have a small cluster (all nodes run Debian 10) and need to remove the internet connections of all slave nodes. The internet cable connection connects to a computer that acts as a firewall, then, that computer sources a switch. All the cluster computers are connected to the switch. The firewall computer redirects all connections to the master node which is in the switch. The connection between nodes and the cluster is done via ssh.

The internet provider changed its policy and now having all those computers connected to the same port is no longer possible. Then, what I want to do is to remove the internet access of all the nodes but keep the connections in the local network. Having internet access in only one node (the master node) is enough.

I have tried many different solutions I found in forums and in the internet. Most of them suggest changing or removing the default gateway. This doesn't work because then the node becomes inaccessible from the other nodes.

If someone knows how to do this I will appreciate it very much.

EDIT:

The masking address for the external connection is 168.176. Internally, the connection between nodes starts with 192.168.
Basically, each PC goes to a port on the switch. 192.168.1.100, 192.168.1.101, 192.168.1.102, etc. You can log in to the cluster via ssh to the master and then for the type of work we use the cluster for, you need to be able to ssh to the other nodes.

Comment: Please provide your addressing scheme. If the addresses start with 192.168 or with 172.16 or with 10 you do not need to mask them as they are private addresses with no value to anyone else

Comment: I don't need to know about your external (public) IP address, thank you. I need to understand why you think you even need to route between the cluster nodes and the master node. And for that I need to see how you've set up your addressing. "192.168" is totally insufficient information

Comment: Just to confirm, the ISP changed its policy to disallow the use of source NAT? To prevent the nodes communicating with the wider internet you could configure this at the firewall?

Comment: Note that the suggestion is to remove the **default** gateway. You can add the routes needed for the secondary nodes to communicate between them.

Answer (score 1):

If all of the nodes, including the master, are on the the same subnet 192.168.1.x/24 then they can communicate directly without any need for a gateway. Only nodes that need Internet access need a default gateway in this scenario, i.e. just the master node.

If this doesn't match your reality you need to provide considerably more detail in your question than you've currently given.